# Multiple Google+ share buttons on single page

Tags: html, google-plus, sharing

I would like to have a website with two different buttons for sharing on google+. These two have to have different summary texts.
I have set meta descriptions like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE">
<meta property="og:description" content="CONTENT">
<meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE_URL">
<meta property="og:url" content="URL">
```

But with such setting both the buttons share the same text, image etc.
Is there any way to change these settings in the sharing link?
*I don't want +1 button.*

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple share buttons on the same page. The share button does not have to appear on the page that you are sharing. The share button's can individually have different URLs that they refer to if you use the [`data-href` attribute](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#script-parameters) (HTML5 mode) or `href` (<g:plus /> mode ).

What you would do is point to different URLs that could serve that the appropriate [snippet data](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) for the given context. If you are using a server-side language such as PHP this is easy, you could have `myfile.php?page=page1` and `myfile.php?page=page2` and then customize the output for those two cases. If you have static content without server-side control, you'd likely have to use two separate pages. If you needed visitors to end up on the same target page, you could use a redirect to push them to the correct page when they follow the link.

That said, you might want to [check the Google+ developer policies](https://developers.google.com/+/policies) to ensure that what you're trying to do is allowed and isn't misleading to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still it would be better to use another solution possibly without such _hack_.

Answer (score 0):

**Add beloaw div where you want to display google share button**

```
<g:plus action="share" href="Your Url" annotation="none"></g:plus>
```

**Add this script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        window.___gcfg = {
            lang: 'en-US'
        };

        (function () {
            var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
        })();
```

this code will use full in repeater too.